# PassportJS JWT: protected-route is Unauthorized in my browser , but Authorized on Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication, and I can't figure out why **in Postman protected-route is available, while in my browser protected-route is Unauthorized.**

I'm a beginner and its first time implementing jwt authentication in my project following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYQSCk-qyTW2ewJ05f_GKHtTIzjynDgjK

**Problem**

/login and /register work fine and I can see from the log they issue a JWT token in the req.headers
like `'Authorization':'Bearer <token>'`, however when I try to access GET /protected-route in my browser, it returns Unauthorized, and I can see no logging from JWTStrategy.

I think req.headers.Authorization is not set to all HTTP requests in the app, but only to `POST /login, /register routes` **So my questions are:**

**Is this `req.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer <toekn>';` correct way to set req headers to all GET and POST request in the app?**

**Does the `jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` checks for Authorization property in req.headers or res.headers?**

I have provided the relevant code snippets please have a look!

**Code:**

**app.js**

```
//...

require('./config/database'); // require the db 

// ...
const passport = require('passport');
const strategy = require('./config/passport').strategy;

// ...

app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(strategy);

// ...


module.exports = app
```

**router/index.js**

```
const router = express.Router(); 

//...

const User = require('../config/database').User;
const passport = require('passport');
const utils = require('../lib/utils');


// register route

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){

const saltHash = utils.genPassword(req.body.password);

console.log("req.body.password is: " + req.body.password)
  const salt = saltHash.salt;
  const hash = saltHash.hash;

  const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      hash: hash,
      salt: salt
  })

  newUser.save()
      .then((user) => {
        
          const jwt = utils.issueJWT(user);
         
          if (jwt){
            req.headers["Authorization"] = jwt.token;
          }
          
          res.redirect('/login')
          
      })
      .catch(err => next(err))
});



// login route


router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){

  User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
      .then((user) => {
          if(!user) {
              res.status(401).json({success: false, msg: "Could not find user "})
          }
          // validate the user 
          const isValid = utils.validPassword(req.body.password, user.hash, user.salt)

    
          if(isValid) {
            // issue a JWT
            const jwt = utils.issueJWT(user);

            if (jwt){
              req.headers["Authorization"] = jwt.token;
            }           
         
            res.redirect("/")

          } else {
              res.status(401).json({success: false, msg: "you entered the wrong password"})
          }
      })
      .catch(err => next(err))

});


// GET protected route 

router.get("/protectd-route", passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), async (req, res, next) => {

  res.render("user/getuser.pug")
next()
})
```

**passport.js**

```
const User = require('../config/database').User;
// ...

const Strategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

/// PUB_KEY
const pathToKey = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'id_rsa_pub.pem');
const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(pathToKey, 'utf8');


// options
const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: PUB_KEY,
    algorithms: ['RS256']
};

// strategy
const strategy = new Strategy(options, (payload, done) => {
  
    User.findOne({_id: payload.sub})
        .then((user) => {
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false)
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => done(err, null))
});


module.exports.strategy = strategy;
```

**utils.js**

- genPassword() - Creating a salt and hash out of it to store in db
- validPassword() - re-hashing user salt and hash to verify
- issueJWT() - signing user with jsonwebtoken

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');

const User = require('../config/database').User;

//...


const pathToKey = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'id_rsa_priv.pem');
const PRIV_KEY = fs.readFileSync(pathToKey, 'utf8');


// validate in /login
function validPassword(password, hash, salt) {
    var hashVerify = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    return hash === hashVerify;
}


// generate in /register
function genPassword(password) {
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    var genHash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    
    return {
      salt: salt,
      hash: genHash
    };
}


// sign 

function issueJWT(user) {
  const _id = user._id;

  const expiresIn = '86400';

  const payload = {
    sub: _id,
    iat: Date.now()
  };

  const signedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { expiresIn: expiresIn, algorithm: 'RS256' });

  return {
    token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
    expires: expiresIn
  }
}

module.exports.validPassword = validPassword;
module.exports.genPassword = genPassword;
module.exports.issueJWT = issueJWT;
```

**Postman**

In Postman, the protected route is showing successfully, with Headers set as above.

[image]

The browser network is showing this, there is **no Authorization property both in response and request headers**

[image]

Clearly, I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated

here is also my db

**database.js**

```
const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI
const connection = mongoose.connection;


mongoose.connect(uri, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000
  })

connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "connection error"))
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection has been established successfully')
  })
  
  
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});
  
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema )

module.exports.User = User;
```

Comment: Try logging the request headers when sending a request to the protected route through the browser, check if the headers are sending correctly, then try logging the verification, if you are getting any errors there.

Comment: I tried, but log inside protected route doesn't get called at all, passport.authenticate() doesn't let it. Did you mean to log without passport.authenticate() in protected route GET method? I tried with the verification, it is working fine, user data is getting verified